# Swift shouldSelectViewController using alertController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have what seems like a normal use case: on selecting a certain tab ('logout' in my case), I want to display an alert asking for confirmation before transitioning.  This seems like it should be handled in the `shouldSelectViewController` function. However, the `alertController` is async, and I'm forced to return a boolean before it completes. It doesn't seem likely that `shouldSelectViewController` should wait for an async task before completing. Is there a better place for me to trigger my confirmation alert before switching views?

This is my code:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if (viewController is Trove.HomeViewController) {
        var shouldSelect = false
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .Default) { (action) in
            shouldSelect = true
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        tabBarController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) { return shouldSelect}
    }
    return true
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the `selecedIndex` property of the `UITabBarController`.

Your new `if statement`:

```
if (viewController is Trove.HomeViewController) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .Default) { (action) in
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0 //CHANGE ME
    }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    tabBarController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) 
    return false
}
```

Comment: Clever!  And there's no infinite loop because the tab is being set programatically.  Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: No Problem. Glad I could help!